# Cassandra: not able to update a map datatype in cql

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cqlsh

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Social ("partitionId" text,"name" text,  "id"   text,  "data1" text, "data2" text,  "data3" map<text,text>, "data4 boolean, "data5" map<text, text>, primary key ("partitionId","name","id"));

const newValue = Object.values({
sId: '6e4d02ddc56bb014fee',
sData: '{"stamina":"yes"}',
rId: 'b1a264ed-b3ss9270316',
re: '101-r'
});

const q = 'UPDATE social SET "data5[?] = ? WHERE "partitionId" = \'social\' AND "id" = ? AND "name" = ?;';


client.execute(q, newValue, { prepare: true }).then(result => console.log(result.wasApplied()));
```

Output:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ResponseError: Undefined column name data5
    at FrameReader.readError

I am using nodejs cassandra driver to update the colums data5 of datatype map , but i get the above error . Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in few attempts.
After a bit of research  from Cassandra docs, I found this:

Cassandra will convert all table/column name in lower case by default. If case sensitive table/column name is required then enclose it in double quotes.

So, I have modified my query like :

```
const q = 'UPDATE Social SET "data5"[?] = ? WHERE "partitionId" = \'router\' AND   "id" = ? AND "name" = ?;';
```

and it worked.